# Excel Macro Leaves Faux Selection lines?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following macro to "reset" a form. It leaves selection lines on the areas on Range(C3:C4) and Rows(32:37). However, they don't seem to be "real" selection lines. If I click somewhere else on the sheet, they don't disappear. If I make a selection that includes these areas and then click out, they do disappear. I want it to stop!

```
For Each cl In Range("B12:B16")
    cl.Value = 0
Next cl
For Each rw In Range("B26:B37")
    rw.EntireRow.ClearContents
Next rw

'Clear Vendor/PO
Range("C3:C4").ClearContents
```

Answer (score 1):

First off you don't need to loop:

```
range("B12:B16").Formula = 0
Rows("26:37").Clearcontents
Range("C3:C4").ClearContents
```

Can you post a screenshot of the issue you are experiencing, i can't really understand that they stay sort of selected, is there some conditional formatting on them that marks them a grey colour if empty or something?

Comment: Here's a screencap of my screen after pushing the Restart Button which runs the Macro in questions: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o84dzv8mc72g2aj/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-14%20at%2011.58.44%20AM.png?dl=0

The selection box on the right hand side is the section I made after running the macro to try to clear the blue lines on the bottom left and the selection box in the upper left. The only way to get rid of those left side selections is to actually create a section box over the areas in question. It's kind of hard to explain!